# Gspread stuck on authorization

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, google-oauth, gspread

So I'm running this code from the [tutorial](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/docs/oauth2.rst) but can't even get through the authorization process.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path/to/oauth.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

table = gc.openall()
```

After n minutes of waiting when I interrupt the process, I see that it hangs on

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1252, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

executing this method `gspread.authorize(credentials)`.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem? I tried with multiple oauth jsons so I guess it's not a problem on Google's side.

I tried reading the json and passing args on my own with the same result.

I created json files from two different Google accounts, one of which is in the company domain, with the same result.

I'm running the code on Ubuntu 16.04, PyCharm 2017.2.4, with Python 3.5 and gspread 0.6.2.

Edit: The exact same problem occurs on Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works, but I literally had to wait over 10 minutes. People running the exact same code on youtube see the output immediately. Still, if you have any idea what's the cause of this delay or how to debug this socket problem, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Tom, I know this is a really old post, but do you recall if you figured out why this was happening? I think it is happening to me...

Comment: Hi @ontologist! Sadly I don't remember what was the issue. As far as I remember I was running it as a cron job and I didn't really care how fast would that be. I remember I was also running it with samba and the next version of gspread was completly incompatible with my implementation. I'm sorry I can't provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I can find resolution.
I have a connection to the Wireguard VPN, after down connection, api works perfect
PS
Sorry for my so bad english

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was following the documentation to access sheet through python and it hanged at the OAuth token generation...

Visiting the auth link in a `private window` solved it.

Either a socket was hanging or switching from *spreadsheet.readonly* to full read-write *spreadsheet* caused some caching cookie issue.