# gspread spontaneously hanging on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

I have some code to open a google sheet:

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='bot/creds.json')
doc = gc.open("Tournaments")
print(doc)
```

The code works completely fine when run on my windows 10 PC:

```
<Spreadsheet 'Tournaments' id:[REMOVED]>
```

However when I run it on my linux server it hangs. When I use Ctrl+C, I get the following:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    doc = gc.open("Tournaments")
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 152, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files(title, folder_id),
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 127, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request("get", url, params=params).json()
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 79, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 476, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 410, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 193, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 161, in _token_endpoint_request
    response_status_ok, response_data = _token_endpoint_request_no_throw(
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 115, in _token_endpoint_request_no_throw
    response = request(method="POST", url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "/home/[REMOVED]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 183, in __call__
    response = self.session.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 314, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The code is stored in a network drive on my server, so both computers are running the exact same code, in the same root folder.

I DONT UNDERSTAND WHAT IM DOING WRONG (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Seems to be a similar issue to this not-really-answered question [Gspread stuck on authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574255/gspread-stuck-on-authorization)

Generally speaking I'm pretty new to the whole web thing so ELI5.

EDIT: Just like the linked question, it does manage to connect after a long time (>10 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

your issue is in your network setup.

As you mentioned: you run the exact same code on 2 different machines. So that might not be the code te problem but most probably the machine

when reading the stack trace we see that it hangs on the method: `sock.connect(sa)` which effectively connects to the host. So if this function hangs it's because your network is not correctly setup.

Fix tour network settings then it should work out of the fox